# PYTHON - Aguardar conclusão de uma cópia de arquivos antes executar os próximos passos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Olá
Estou criando uma rotina de backup que consiste em copiar uma série de arquivos de uma pasta para outra.
Após a cópia do arquivo eu quero executar um getsize para recuperar o tamanho do diretório.
O problema é que o getsize é executado antes da cópia finalizar. Como faço para que cada passo seja executado somente com o término do anterior?

```
import os
from datetime import date

today = str(date.today()).replace("-","")
todayformated = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
source = "D:\\Origem\\"
destination = "D:\\Destino\\"
sourcebkpini = "D:\\backup.ini"
backupini = """[BACKUP]
DataBackup="""+todayformated+"""
DirDestinoBackup=
"""

def execBackup():
    try:
        os.popen('mkdir '+ destination+today)
        os.popen('copy ' + source + '* ' + destination+today, 'w')
        with open(sourcebkpini, 'w') as ini:
            ini.write(backupini)
            print('Calculando tamanho do diretório', os.path.getsize(destination+today))
    except:
        print("Erro")

execBackup()


retorno:

Calculando tamanho do diretório 4096
D:\Origem\imovel.DB
D:\Origem\imovel.MB
D:\Origem\imovel.PX
D:\Origem\imovel.XG0
```

Comment: Troque `os.popen` por `subprocess.getoutput`.

Comment: Uma solução mais agradável e que funcionará bem em qualquer sistema operacional é usar o `shutil.copyfile()` ao invés de chamar diretamente os comandos do sistema operacional.